# On click of link, open outlook window with attached document (clicked) - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to do the following task but unable to do so in Angular2.

I have a link of document on web page, for example: `abc.pdf`. I want the functionality, if the user will click on this document link. The Outlook window should open with prior attached this document into it.

I want to achieve this only in Angular2.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it, because it isn't possible.

When you open a mailing client

1. You can't chose which client to open : it depends on the user's PC configuration
2. You can't attach files. This would be a major security issue.

Sending a mail rests on the [`mailto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/aa767737%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) protocol, feel free to look at the documentation.

Now, if you are looking for a solution, I would advise you to store the file on your server and share a link to download it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.